# Tata Docomo 3g unable to connect using Huawei E303C

Tags: usb-modem, 3g, mobile-broadband, huawei

I am trying to connect to internet using Tata Docomo 3g using Huawei E303C usb modem. With the same modem I am able to connect to Idea Cellular and Reliance networks. I have tried using "TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNET" and "TATADOCOMO3G" PAN's. While trying to connect I am getting message "Modem network Disconnected". I am using Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

Answer (score 1):

In case it helps some one, `TATA.DOCOMO.INTERNETHVC` instead may help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect without any issues. Your problem seems to be strange. When searched on net, found this [answer](http://www.hitxp.com/ask-guru/2012/01/04/how-to-enable-tata-docomo-3g-internet-in-ubuntu/).

Do the normal steps as we do for all other devices( Reliance, MTS) but once it asks you for the service provider details don't choose "Tata docomo 3g" or "Tata docomo 3g pan" instead select the option button **I can’t find my provider and I wish to enter manually** and in the textbox enter as given below
**TATA DOCOMO UMTS**

For APN use **tatadocomo3g**

Comment: I have too searched for the solutions and found the same solutions. But strangely none are working. The usb modem is perfectly with Xp.

Answer (score 0):

I called the customer support for same issue ,they told that they did not support linux os.
Only windows xp and 7 are suported. only support pc suite connections usb modems are thus they blocked.